# Consulting about loan calculator function

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm trying to do a loan calculator where you can input the amount you want to borrow, the amount of months that you plan to pay everything and select a type of credit (car, studies, home, etc) that determines the interest rate of each.

In JavaScript, I called values from *Loan Amount* - *Months to Pay* - dropdown list with *Type of Credits* that provides different interest values. I try to work around this [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1xy8.png) and write it in text like this:

```
p*(r*(1+r)^n/1-(1+r)^n);
```

Am I right with the formula I'm using to get Fixed monthly payment -- am I right writing the formula in text/code way? I'm also doing the output this way:

```
document.getElementById("id-name").innerHTML = p*(r*(1+r)^n/1-(1+r)^n);
```

Is this the right way to do it or should i do the formula in another `var z` and call `innerHTML = z` ?? Finally, this would be the full JS function with the input variables:

```
function CALCULADORA() {
 var x = document.getElementById("list").value;
 var i = x/100;
 var c = document.getElementById("cuotas").value;
 var y =  document.getElementById("valor").value;
 document.getElementById("CALCULATOR").innerHTML =  y*(x*(1+x)^c/1-(1+x)^c);
}

/*
x is Interest rate in percentage given by a dropdown list
i is Percentage / 100
c is Months to pay loan
y is Loan value 
*/
```

The issue is that not getting the full formula, my result is only the Loan value divided by months to be paid -- that is what I got displayed. Thanks to any help you can give me! This is one of my first codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are converting those values to numbers before trying to math on them. Specifically when adding. Something like  `1+x` will not give you what you expect when x is a string like `0.2`.

Assuming those values can be decimals, you will need to do something like:

```
 var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("list").value);
 var i = x/100;
 var c =  parseFloat(document.getElementById("cuotas").value);
 var y =  parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor").value);
```

Comment: Thanks! yes, X is a percentage with . decimal value. that's why I need the `var i` to convert percentage into numeric value into the formula

Comment: keep in mind that in this part of your code: `y*(x*(1+x)^c/1-(1+x)^c)` you are using `x` directly without it being converted into a number, so `1+x` is likely not what you expect.

Comment: yes, it was to make sure that X variable is working... however i changed the X for the "var i" but the formula still not work :(

Comment: I would output the values of each variable to make sure they are what you expect:
`console.log(x, i, c, y)` will show the values in the browsers developer console. If those numbers are as you expect, then perhaps your formula is incorrect?

Comment: sooo, all the variables worked! must be the function but must be about syntaxis, because the formula works for monthly payment

Comment: Are you sure that formula is correct? Most loan calculations don't use the bitwise 'or' operator which is what `^` is in Javascirpt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211028/discussion-between-harry-bougard-and-mcgraphix).

Comment: Sorry... I can't use SO chat from the network where I am

Comment: oh sorry, i think its wrong formula or something. i've tried to split the formula into other 'var's but didnt get the result. gonna change the formula and try other but thanks!